# hide/show uiimageview with animation when clicking button

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, animation, swift2

how can I implement that when I click on button, my Image moves out of the screen with animation and when I click again on the button , comes back to its place?

Comment: Please show some code, what have you tried?

Comment: Add images to uiview and animate uiview using block. You can play with what kind of animation you want in your app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the `button` click event, simply animate the `x coordinate of origin` of the `imageView` according to your requirement.

**Example:**

```
@IBAction func onTapButton(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    if sender.isSelected
    {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, animations: {
            self.imageView.frame.origin.x = 0.0
        })
    }
    else
    {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, animations: {
            self.imageView.frame.origin.x = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        })
    }
    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
}
```

The above code will work as follows:

1. when `selecting` `button`, `imageView's` `x coordinate of origin` is moved to `extreme right` of the screen (`UIScreen.main.bounds.width`)
2. when `de-selecting` `button`, `imageView's` `x coordinate of origin` is moved to `extreme left` of the screen (`0.0`)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to move left-

```
func moveToLeft()
{
    var frame = imageView.frame
    frame.origin.x = -imageView.frame.size.width //Adjust this value according to your need
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {() -> Void in
        self.imageView.frame = frame
    }, completion: {(_ finished: Bool) -> Void in
        /*done*/
    })
}
```

Use this code to move right-

```
func moveToRight()
{
    var frame = imageView.frame
    frame.origin.x = 0 //Adjust this value according to your need
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {() -> Void in
        self.imageView.frame = frame
    }, completion: {(_ finished: Bool) -> Void in
        /*done*/
    })
}
```